# Measure throughput at datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to measure the throughput at each datanode by measuring the time taken for each read/write operation. It is very confusing to read through the million functions and find out where this is happening. Could someone list the series of calls made while reading/writing a block of data?  am using version 1.0.1. Alternatively, if there is already an API which measures this at the datanode I could use that information.

Comment: Regarding your bounty comment: If you blacklist a node, it will no longer participate in the cluster, and so throughput will never recover.

Comment: Hey Bug Catcher, any thoughts on my answer below?

Comment: @likeitlikeit I did something on the lines of the existing policy for heartbeats: give it three chances and if it is still bad then blacklist it. Not intended for practical use anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important classes to study to measure throughput are `FSDataOutputStream` for writes and `FSDataInputStream` for reads.

**File Read:** The first thing that a node does when reading a file is call `open()` on the `FileSystem` object. At this point, you know that this node will begin reading shortly and you can place code after this call returns successfully to prepare for your measurements. Calling `open()` on HDFS instantiates a `DistributedFileSystem` who communicates with the NameNode to collect block locations (sorted according to calling node proximity). Finally, the `DistributedFileSystem` object returns `FSDataInputStream` ("sees" reading a file) who in turn wraps `DFSInputStream` ("sees" reading blocks, handles failure). Your measurements would be scoped within the `read()` and `close()` call on the `FSDataInputStream`.

**File Write:** The node will call `create()` on the `FileSystem`. Various checks are made at this point that encompass file permissions, availability etc, but upon successful completion it returns a `FSDataOutputStream` object who wraps a `DFSOutputStream`. The same concept applies where one sees a continuous write the other handles the coherency of the replication factor (i.e. one write = three writes) and failure. Similarly to a read, your measurements would be scoped within the `write()` and `close()` call on the `FSDataInputStream`.

In order to do this globally for all nodes in your cluster, you would need to override these methods as part of the distribution of Hadoop you share in your cluster.

Comment: Doesn't explain how to aggregate stats for each data node. Client nodes can't be expected to profile the individual data nodes and send information to the name node. Anyway, since my need has passed, I will accept this answer